# Редукція-зведення, редукційна-?

Tags: вибір-слова, словотворення

Якщо до слова *редукція* можна в деякому контексті підібрати відповідних *зведення*, то як бути з *редукційна*?

Наприклад, *редукційний алгоритм* робить *редукцію*.

Comment: *зведеннєва*?..

Comment: Зауважте, що "редукцію" можна замінити не просто на "зведення", а обов'язково на "зведення до", отже не зручно буде використовувати звідна, зведеннєва, адже перехідність, на мій погляд, втрачається, при чому критично

Comment: А як щодо «звідна»?

Comment: @Sasha *звідна* - це та яку можна *звести*

Comment: Можете додати зміст використання слова у вашому випадку?

Comment: @Yola, а мовний — це той, який можна мовити? По-моєму, не обов'язково. По-моєму, тут ще може бути значенния «той, що стосується зводу», «той, що стосується мови». (Особливо, якщо поставити наголос _зві́дний_. Хоча словники рідко дозволяють _[зві́дний](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=звідний&highlight=on)_, частіше [_звідни́й_ — навіть у значенні «стос. до зводу»](//services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=34871&page=1109), але по-моєму такий неологізм буде кращим за _зведеннєвий_.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

За аналогією з *мовлення - мовленнєва* буде *зведеннєва*. Наприклад, *зведеннєва функція*, така фукнція може виконувати *зведення*.

Comment: Я не певен, що в утворені подібних прикметників *спілкувАння* стоїть в одному ряду із *зведЕння* і *мовлЕння*. Хоча може дійсно просто треба звикнути.

Comment: За логікою «дія — результат» мало б бути так… Продукція — це результат; дія — це продукування; редакція — це результат; дія — це редагування; відповідно, редукція — це результат, редукування — це дія. Мовний і редукційний — це від результату (мова й редукція); мовленнєвий і зведеннєвий — це від дії (мовлення, редукування). Відповідно, якщо Ви шукаєте прикметник від результату (редукція → редукційний), то це має бути «звід → звідний» (так, звідний позначає _зокрема_ «який можна звести», але не лише це); а «зведення→зведеннєвий» є аналогом «редукування→[редукуваннєвий]», а не «… →редукційний».

Comment: (@AndriyIvanchenko, це частково й до Вас теж.) «Я не певен… спілкувАння стоїть в одному ряду із зведЕння і мовлЕння» — так, справді, за логікою «дія (1) — подія (2) — наслідок (3)» (яку я не дуже люблю, але, наприклад, при перекладі книги керувалися саме нею) зведЕння/мовлЕння і спілдкувАння належать до різних категорій. Розв'язання (1) — розв'язування (2) — розв'язок (3). ЗведЕння/мовлЕння — це як розв'язання (1), а спілкувАння — це як розв'язування (2).

Answer (score 1):

СУМ-11

***[Редукція](http://sum.in.ua/s/redukcija)*** **5.** ек. Зведення складного виробничого процесу до простішого в умовах товарного виробництва.

***[Редукційний](http://sum.in.ua/s/redukcijnyj)***  а, е, спец. Стос. до редукції.

***[Зведення](http://sum.in.ua/s/zvedennja)*** **1.** Дія за значенням звести 5—12, 16. Сполучення всіх подібних між собою членів многочлена в один член називається зведенням подібних членів многочлена

***[Зведенний](http://sum.in.ua/s/zvedenyj)*** а, е. **1.** Дієпр. пас. мин. ч. до звести.

Отже, *редукція-зведення, редукційна-зведена.*

Comment: Як *дієпр. пас. мин. ч.* відповідає *стос. до*?

Comment: @Yola стос. до *звести*, *зведення* дія за значенням *звести*.

Comment: це стосування може бути різним наприклад *редукційний алгоритм* - це той, що виконує редукцію. А *зведений алгоритм* - це той алгоритм який звели.

Comment: @Yola в Вашому питанні немає контексту, в якому саме замінювати *редукційна*. Доводиться лише здогадуватися, що саме Ви запитуєте.

Comment: Ну, просто *редукційна*:) Не *редукована* чи *зредукована*, а *редукційна*.

Comment: @Yola, загалом Mariia Matskevych права, що варто було б пояснити, що означає «редукційна» (у тому значенні, що Ви шукаєте).

Comment: "Ну, просто редукційна:) Не редукована чи зредукована, а редукційна" - якщо почитати етимологічний словник, то основним коренeм є duc. Тобто можливо сказати редукована. Не вдається знайти що означає -tio в re-duc-tio, щоб розібратися.

Comment: @Sasha я не шукаю якогось конкретного значення *редукційна*. Ну от ми можемо сказати *еволюційна біологія*, а це щось *редукційне*.

Comment: @Yola, якщо чесно, мені здається «перекласти слово в усіх можливих значеннях» або «знайти синоніми слова в усіх можливих значеннях» (а не в якомусь конкретному контексті) — це просто лютий «too broad» (дивно, що на Вас інші не накинулися — зазвичай, навпаки, я намагаються захистити автора потенційно корисного дописа від нападок у стилі «недостатньо хороший допис» — а тут навіть я уже впевнений, що це занадто широке питання). Навіть якщо Вам потрібно _в усіх значеннях_ — наведіть хоча б пару прикладів контесту (зокрема, завдяки їм має бути зрозуміло, чому…

Comment: …інші запропоновані варіанти не підходять).